# How to set the server name on install

Tags: sql-server, database, installation, host

Last time I installed a SQL Server somewhere in the process I named it like `MyDataBase` somewhere and when I got done installing I could connect to `MyDatabase` in the SSMS box and the top left showed that.

This time I must have missed something because it just had the first part of the machine host name, so like `12345server.host.net` the server name to connect to was `12345server`.

I'm fine with reinstalling, but I can't seem to find where I missed this step.

Comment: Sounds like you're referring to the *instance name* - chosen on the first stage of the install wizard.

Comment: The server name is inherited from the host name of the machine when SQL Server first gets installed. If you rename the host you also need to rename the corresponding entry in `sys.servers`. It sounds like you're talking about Aliases in the SSMS connect-to-database dialog, though. You can configure those in SQL Server (version) Configuration Manager by way of SQL Native Client (version) Configuration (32bit/64bit) > Aliases.